# Merging zip code based polygons to create sales territories?

Tags: polygon, software-recommendations

I have access the full data set of the KML file shown here: 
http://www.maptechnica.com/downloads/samples/mt_2014a_kml_us_zcta5_sample.tar.gz

Here's what it basically looks like: http://www.maptechnica.com/us-zip-code-boundary-and-geodata

It's basically a bunch of polygons that match (close enough) ZIP code boundaries. What I also have is a table that shows which zip codes go with which territory (i.e., a territory overlaps multiple ZIP codes).

I'm looking for a tool that I can use to merge these two sources together to create new polygons consisting of the group of zip code polygons that make up a territory.

Mapping is completely new to me, so I'm not even sure which tools I need to use.

Ideally I'd like to avoid making a big software purchase.

Comment: I'm not sure what output you want, or rather where you want to use it or what you want to do with it. It sounds to me like you need to simply add a territory attribute to the zip polys (and you can then display all zips in a territory the same way, without actually creating a new poly). Or maybe you *do* want to go a step further and actually create territory polys. Both can be accomplished in QGIS, which is free, but if you're wanting to stay in KML (as opposed to going back and forth) that might be a different thing.

Comment: I have answered a similar question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124374/getting-attribute-data-from-one-dataset-to-another/124529#124529 using buildings however the same software (QGIS) and techniques will most likely apply in this case. You will need to do most of the work in shapefiles which can then be converted to KML/KMZ with an add-on like http://www.igismap.com/convert-shapefile-kml-qgis/ (I neither endorse or recommend this product, it is meant to be indicative)

Comment: When seeking a software recommendation I think it is best to research/ask at the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.