# Joining parcel/building attributes based on coordinates

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinates, attribute-joins

I downloaded a building footprint shapefile for a city and imported it as a vector layer in QGIS. I was hoping to see street address information in the attribute table, but there was none. I subsequently downloaded and imported a shapefile containing the land parcels for the same city (which DO have street addresses), and it overlays nicely such that buildings appear within parcels.

I would like to join the attribute tables such that my building footprint file contains addresses; however, there is no common key on which I can join (I see a Shape_STAr and Shape_STLe but can't figure out what these are).

Is there a way for me to (programmatically via a framework or otherwise) determine which buildings fall inside a parcel based on the coordinates such that I could join the data in the manner I desire?

I've done some Google searches but can't figure out where to start.

Comment: You're looking for the Spatial Query or Join Attributes by Location tools.

Comment: Related? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124374/getting-attribute-data-from-one-dataset-to-another/124529#124529

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as though you have no matching attributes to join you will need to perform a spatial join. This is under Vector>Data Management Tools>Join Attributes by Location

[image: Spatial Join Example]

Comment: Looks like the start of a good answer, could you expand a little explaining what a spatial join actually is, and perhaps give an example.

Comment: This proved very straightforward; I used an option that made the operation left-joinish. A cursory verification checks out. It seems that nearly all the buildings were able to find a parcel in which they live, and a few spot checks showed the right address for the building. Thanks!