# Joining custom shapefile to csv data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have a custom shapefile which I want to join to geo-coded (Lat and Long) protest data from a .csv file in QGIS. I wanted to know how this was possible without having unique IDs.

In other words, I have a shapefile that doesn't conform to standard boundaries such as administrative levels, districts or municipalities therefore I cannot easily join each dataset by a common attribute.

Is there a way of getting around this, e.g. visualising both the shapefile and point data and then working backwards to spatially join the two?

Answer (score 1):

A spatial join would be required, as long as the shapefile and csv are in the same CRS - [Joining Parcel/Building Attributes Based on Coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150369/joining-parcel-building-attributes-based-on-coordinates/150404#150404)